# Testing Google/Facebook oAuth with behat

Tags: google-oauth, bdd, facebook-oauth, behat

I wonder how should i test Google/Facebook oAuth with behat? 
Should I do it? 
If so how?

I use selenium2 WebDriver

Thanks in advance !

Answer (score 0):

You don't even need Selenium to test it.
Just mock both apis and test that the logic on your side works. You should mock everything that doesn't belong to your app.

Just be sure that you mock both Apis properly and get notified if any of them change.